# Incomplete Userstory and Burn down chart

Tags: scrum

I have a quick question about scrum and user stories.

I am working on a little project for university and I have decided to tackle the functionality using Scrum and user stories, I know Scrum is usually done with a set of team members but in my case I am doing this alone with a project supervisor.

I understand what goes into a user stories and the pointing and priority system such as (Must, Should, Could, Wont)

Now coming when i'm coming towards an end of an iteration and lets say about half of the user story is complete.

An example of one my user story is:

"A user needs to be able to record equipment"

I created little sub-tasks for this user story, I have reached all of them apart from 1 sub-task and i have reached the end of the iteration. I gave this user story a point 8.

- Now im not sure if i can include this user story into the burndown chart, or do I wait until the sub task is complete, before adding to the chart.
- I also wanted to ask could i base my Burn Down chart based on how may tasks i have completed in a user story, or is always based on how many user stories are fully completed including testing etc.

  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are two traditional burndown charts (neither is required by Scrum per-se): the Sprint burndown and the Release burndown.

> Now im not sure if i can include this user story into the burndown
>   chart, or do I wait until the sub task is complete, before adding to
>   the chart.
>   It's up to you.  The purpose of the Release burndown is to understand what's remaining.  That feature can't be shipped so just be incredibly clear about that.  If this keeps happening, figure out why.

Velocity, the empirical amount you've been able to completely finish, is there to help you know what you should forecast for the next sprint.  This sprint that is only partially done so empiricism tells you don't forecast that amount of work again.

> I also wanted to ask could i base my Burn Down chart based on how may
>   tasks i have completed in a user story, or is always based on how many
>   user stories are fully completed including testing etc.
>   The Sprint Burndown in which teams traditionally sum remaining tasks or task hours is meant to help you understand if you need to renegotiate the Sprint forecast (up or down).

I would not recommend trying to burndown tasks outside of the sprint.  To burndown tasks at the release level and understand what's remaining, you have to estimate a LOT of small grained details.  How you solve problems will change from your current beliefs and how long it takes will change.  You will also undoubtedly not do everything you think you're going to do at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

A burndown chart represents the quantity of remaining estimated hours of work left in the sprint on any given day so don't include anything outside the sprint.  Typically a story is estimated in points which are a reflection of the effort and risk attached to the story by the team members (in this case, you).  When a story is broken down into tasks, those tasks are typically estimated in hours - the best practice is a task should take no more than a day or the amount of time until your next Daily Scrum.

I think an underlying question within your question may be "Do I get to count the portion of the story that I finished when the sprint ends?".  Sadly the answer is "No". The best way to use Scrum is to be very black-and-white about finishing a story - it's either completely "done" or not.  No middle ground.  What done means to a team is up to them as long as it's defined up front and not a moving target. In my case, we use the rule that it's done if its "shippable quality" with the QA members as the referee.

If a story isn't shippable, it's failed regardless of whether it's 50% or 99% done.  No partial credit.  If this happens, the story is re-estimated in points, put back on the backlog and the Product Owner gets a chance to see if s/he wants to pick it back up for the next sprint.  It's also a great time to re-evaluate the estimate for the story - an 8pt story is large for a normal sized team, for a 1 person team, it's way too big IMO.  The target story size for a team should ideally be around 2-5 points.  Finally, if you couldn't finish the 8pt story, it's a signal that your velocity is too high and you need to do less points in the next sprint.